# How write a regex that preserve the order of appearence with python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

Given the following `string` i would like to extract a tuple such that the tuple preserve the appeareance of an assosiated id (POS tag). The order is: `NCFS000`, `AQ0CS0`. They need to be concecutive, no other id/tag can be between `NCFS000`, `AQ0CS0`.

For example:

```
string= ''' Hola hola I 1
compis compis NCMS000 0.500006
! ! Fat 1

No no RN 0.998045
sabía saber VMII3S0 0.592869
como como CS 0.999289
se se P00CN000 0.465639
ponía poner VMII3S0 0.65
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
conocí conocer VMIS1S0 1
esta este DD0FS0 0.986779
y y CC 0.999962
es ser VSIP3S0 1
que que CS 0.437483
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
sencilla sencillo AQ0FS0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
utilizar utilizar VMN0000 1
! ! Fat 1

Todo todo DI0MS0 0.560961
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gustazo gustazo NCMS000 1
cuando cuando CS 0.985595
estamos estar VAIP1P0 1
aprendiendo aprender VMG0000 1
para para SPS00 0.999103
emancipar emancipar VMN0000 1
nos nos PP1CP000 1
, , Fc 1
que que CS 0.437483
si si CS 0.99954
nos nos PP1CP000 0.935743
ponen poner VMIP3P0 1
facilidad facilidad NCFS000 1
con con SPS00 1
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
tareas tarea NCFP000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
pues pues CS 0.998047
mejor mejor AQ0CS0 0.873665
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
mejor mejor AQ0CS0 0.873665
. . Fp 1

Antes_de antes_de SPS00 1
esta este PD0FS000 0.0132212
teníamos tener VMII1P0 1
otra otro DI0FS0 0.803899
de de SPS00 0.999984
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
marca marca NCFS000 0.972603
Otsein otsein NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
estas este DD0FP0 0.97043
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
van ir VMIP3P0 1
incluidas incluir VMP00PF 1
en en SPS00 1
el el DA0MS0 1
mobiliario mobiliario NCMS000 0.476077
y y CC 0.999962
además además RG 1
era ser VSII1S0 0.491262
de de SPS00 0.999984
carga carga NCFS000 0.952569
superior superior AQ0CS0 0.992424
, , Fc 1
pero pero CC 0.999764
tan tan RG 1
antigua antiguo AQ0FS0 0.953488
que que CS 0.437483
según según SPS00 0.995943
mi mi DP1CSS 0.999101
madre madre NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
nadie nadie PI0CS000 1
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
podía poder VMII3S0 0.63125
tocar tocar VMN0000 1
porque porque CS 1
solo solo RG 0.0472103
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
entendía entender VMII3S0 0.65
ella él PP3FS000 1
. . Fp 1

Esta este PD0FS000 0.0132212
es ser VSIP3S0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
marca marca NCFS000 0.972603
Aeg aeg NP00000 1
y y CC 0.999962
dentro_de dentro_de SPS00 1
este este DD0MS0 0.960092
tipo tipo NCMS000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
lavadoras lavadora NCFP000 0.411969
de de SPS00 0.999984
esta este DD0FS0 0.986779
marca marca NCFS000 0.972603
las lo PP3FPA00 0.0289466
había haber VAII1S0 0.353863
más más RG 1
caras caro AQ0FP0 0.417273
o o CC 0.999769
más más RG 1
baratas barato AQ0FP0 0.3573
y y CC 0.999962
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
digamos decir VMSP1P0 0.785925
que que CS 0.437483
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
en en SPS00 1
el el DA0MS0 1
punto punto NCMS000 1
medio medio AQ0MS0 0.314286
. . Fp 1

Es ser VSIP3S0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
color color NCMS000 1
blanco blanco AQ0MS0 0.598684
y y CC 0.999962
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
carga carga NCFS000 0.952569
frontal frontal AQ0CS0 0.657209
, , Fc 1
con con SPS00 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
capacidad capacidad NCFS000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
6kg 6kg Z 1
. . Fp 1

En en SPS00 1
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
a_pesar_de a_pesar_de SPS00 1
ser ser VSN0000 0.940705
cuatro 4 Z 1
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
ponen poner VMIP3P0 1
lavadoras lavadora NCFP000 0.411969
casi casi RG 1
todos todo DI0MP0 0.624221
o o CC 0.999769
todos todo DI0MP0 0.624221
los el DA0MP0 0.976481
días día NCMP000 1
. . Fp 1

En en SPS00 1
su su DP3CS0 1
parte parte NCFS000 0.499183
de de SPS00 0.999984
arriba arriba RG 0.986014
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
" " Fe 1
; ; Fx 1
zona zona NCFS000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
mandos mando NCMP000 1
" " Fe 1
; ; Fx 1
, , Fc 1
donde donde PR000000 0.967437
se se P00CN000 0.465639
puede poder VMIP3S0 0.999117
echar echar VMN0000 1
el el DA0MS0 1
detergente detergente NCMS000 0.49273
, , Fc 1
aunque aunque CC 1
en en SPS00 1
nuestro nuestro DP1MSP 0.94402
caso caso NCMS000 0.99812
lo lo PP3CNA00 0.271177
a a SPS00 1
el el DA0MS0 1
ser ser VSN0000 0.940705
gel gel NCMS000 1
lo lo PP3CNA00 0.271177
ponemos poner VMIP1P0 1
directamente directamente RG 1
junto_con junto_con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
ropa ropa NCFS000 1
. . Fp 1

Luego luego RG 0.996689
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
rueda rueda NCFS000 0.72093
para para SPS00 0.999103
elegir elegir VMN0000 1
el el DA0MS0 1
programa programa NCMS000 0.953488
y y CC 0.999962
los el DA0MP0 0.976481
intermitentes intermitente NCMP000 0.342773
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
indican indicar VMIP3P0 1
en en SPS00 1
que que CS 0.437483
paso paso NCMS000 0.905738
de de SPS00 1
el el DA0MS0 1
programa programa NCMS000 0.953488
estaba estar VAII1S0 0.5
. . Fp 1

Como como CS 0.999289
todas todo PI0FP000 0.0490506
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
programas programa NCMP000 0.97619
más más RG 1
cortos corto AQ0MP0 1
y y CC 0.999962
más más RG 1
largos largo AQ0MP0 0.97619
, , Fc 1
incluso incluso RG 0.996383
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
programa programa NCMS000 0.953488
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
seria seriar VMIP3S0 0.151546
como como CS 0.999289
lavar lavar VMN0000 1
a a SPS00 0.996023
mano mano NCFS000 0.992095
y y CC 0.999962
otro otro DI0MS0 0.612994
ideal ideal NCMS000 0.5
para para SPS00 0.999103
estores estor NCMP000 1
, , Fc 1
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
salen salir VMIP3P0 0.972603
casi casi RG 1
secos seco AQ0MP0 1
y y CC 0.999962
planchaditos planchar VMP00PM 0.691767
para para SPS00 0.999103
colgar colgar VMN0000 1
y y CC 0.999962
ya ya RG 0.999395
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
. . Fp 1

Es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
fácil fácil AQ0CS0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
aprender aprender VMN0000 1
la lo PP3FSA00 1
y y CC 0.999962
además además RG 1
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
indicador indicador NCMS000 0.64273
por por SPS00 1
sonido sonido NCMS000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
cuando cuando CS 0.985595
acaba acabar VMIP3S0 0.992958
, , Fc 1
lista listar VMIP3S0 0.220088
para para SPS00 0.999103
abrir abrir VMN0000 1
y y CC 0.999962
tender tender VMN0000 1
. . Fp 1

Por por SPS00 1
decir decir VMN0000 0.997512
algo algo PI0CS000 0.900246
malo malo AQ0MS0 0.657087
de de SPS00 0.999984
ella él PP3FS000 1
, , Fc 1
sería ser VSIC1S0 0.5
que que CS 0.437483
cuando cuando CS 0.985595
centrifuga centrifugar VMIP3S0 0.994859
, , Fc 1
algo algo PI0CS000 0.900246
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
hace hacer VMIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
, , Fc 1
pues pues CS 0.998047
vibra vibrar VMIP3S0 0.994856
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
poco poco RG 0.542435
y y CC 0.999962
se se P00CN000 0.465639
nota notar VMIP3S0 0.419995
el el DA0MS0 1
ruido ruido NCMS000 1
jeje jeje NCMS000 0.833445
, , Fc 1
pero pero CC 0.999764
no no RN 0.998134
se se P00CN000 0.465639
mueve mover VMIP3S0 0.994868
de de SPS00 0.999984
su su DP3CS0 1
sitio sitio NCMS000 0.980769
! ! Fat 1
! ! Fat 1

Saludillos saludillos NP00000 0.411768
! ! Fat 1

'''
```

What is all ready done is to extract that tuple with a regex with:

```
import re
tuple = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000|AQ0CS0)',string)
id1 = "NCFS000"
id2 = "AQ0CS0"
arr = []
for i in range(0, len(tuple)-1):
    if tupla[i][1]==id1 and tuple[i+1][1]==id2:
        arr.append(tuple[i])
        arr.append(tuple[i+1])
print arr
```

the output is the following:

```
[('casa', 'NCFS000'), ('mejor', 'AQ0CS0'), ('carga', 'NCFS000'), ('superior', 'AQ0CS0')]`
```

The problem with output this is that if you check out `string`, this side of the tuple dont preserve the order of appeareance(`NCFS000`, `AQ0CS0`):

`('casa', 'NCFS000'), ('mejor', 'AQ0CS0')` since:

> **casa casa NCFS000**
>
> pues pues CS
>
> **mejor mejor AQ0CS0**

Are not consecutive, by the other hand if you check out the other side of the tuple:

```
('carga', 'NCFS000'), ('superior', 'AQ0CS0')
```

They are consecutive, since they follow the order (`NCFS000`, `AQ0CS0`) i.e. they have no other tag between them:

> **carga carga NCFS000**
>
> **superior superior AQ0CS0**

How can i fix the code in order to just write the tuples that follow the `NCFS000`, `AQ0CS0` order?

Comment: Your code only checks that the matches are consecutive **in `tuple`** (which is terrible name for the variable, as it shadows a built-in and the variable *isn't* a `tuple`). If you want to ensure that the matches are on consecutive lines **in `string`**, you will have to modify the regex.

Comment: So `('casa', 'NCFS000'), ('mejor', 'AQ0CS0')` should NOT be a match because `CS` is between?

Comment: If I am understanding what you want, just cahnge your regex to something like `^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)`

Comment: @dawg yes, they need to be consecutive,let me try your regex. thank yo guys

Comment: @dawg: If you want to use `^` to match start-of-line, you'll need to add the `re.MULTILINE` flag. But really, you don't need it; `\n(\w+)` will work in exactly the same places `\n^(\w+)` will, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @dawg i tried with your regex and it doesnt work, how can i aproach this problem?

Comment: @samsmith: Did you use `re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)',string, re.M)`?

Comment: Yes: `tuple = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)',string, re.M)
print "\n this is daw's tuple:"
print tuple` and this is the output: `>>>[]`

Comment: thank´s dawg. But there´s another issue.... I didnt put the complete string check the edit of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `re.M` flag and use this regex:

```
^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eE2bO4/1)

Or, with your example string:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)',string, re.M)
[('carga', 'NCFS000', 'superior', 'AQ0CS0')]
```

---

With your updated string, you need to account for the trailing digits:

```
^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\s[0-9.]+\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eE2bO4/2)

In Python:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\s[0-9.]+\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)', txt, re.M)
[('carga', 'NCFS000', 'superior', 'AQ0CS0'), ('carga', 'NCFS000', 'frontal', 'AQ0CS0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* postprocess the tuples by fixing your code, or writing simpler code like this:

```
for entry, next_entry in zip(tup, tup[1:]):
    if entry[1] == 'NCFS000' and next_entry[1] == 'AQ0CS0':
        # good, do something with entry and next_entry
```

… that still isn't going to catch the case where there were other, unmatched, lines between the two, because you've already thrown that information away.

While you could instead match *every* line (replace the `(NCFS000|AQ0CS0)` in your regexp with `(\w+)`, and then check them this way, it seems like it would be a lot easier to just rewrite your regexp to capture only those cases in the first place:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s\w+\sNCFS000\n(\w+)\s\w+\sAQ0CS0', string)
for entry, next_entry in matches:
    # no need for a check
```

(As a side note, don't name your variables things like `tuple` and `string`. Besides not saying anything useful about the contents of those variables, that also overshadows, respectively, a type and a module that you probably don't want to hide.)

Comment: Sorry.. i`ll change my variables

Answer (score 0):

Just split `string` into rows and check successive rows:

```
rows = string.splitlines()
for i in range(0, len(tuple)-1):
    if re.search('NCFS000'), rows[i]) and re.search('AQ0CS0', rows[i+1]):
        arr.append(rows[i])
        arr.append(rows[i+1])
```

**Notes:**

1. This is not the most elegant (i.e., "pythonic") way to write your loop, but it's closest to what you were doing. Instead of working with indices, you could also use @abarnert's `zip` approach-- just use it on the complete list of rows.
2. Using `re.search` above is overkill for this example, since you could just say `if "NCFS000" in rows[i]`. But you might have more complex tests. You could also split each row into a triple and check the third element-- it's nicer but unnecessary in this case since your IDs will not match any real words. Use whatever suits you.